# Mini PCIe wireless card, Shuttle SZ68R5

Tags: wireless-networking, pci-express, antenna, shuttle

I know very little about (wireless) networking. I just bought and installed the [Intel Centrino Ultimate-N 6300](http://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B0038A9HSK/ref=oh_details_o01_s00_i00?ie=UTF8&psc=1), but didn't know that I also need an antenna and a cable (or a couple of) to connect the antenna to the card. I have a Shuttle SZ68R5, and the manual does tell me where the antenna should stick out of (I think). BUT, it doesn't tell me what antenna to buy, and what cable (or how many of them) I should buy to connect the antenna to the wireless card. All it said was that the cable should be 30cm long. I'm looking at [this](http://www.amazon.co.uk/TP-Link-TL-ANT2408CL-2-4GHz-Omni-Directional-Antenna/dp/B002VYP5QW/ref=wl_it_dp_o_pC_nS_nC?ie=UTF8&colid=2UFUNANT7G7Q0&coliid=I16I0B6Q3UZSKH) antenna and don't know whether it's the right one. Could someone please tell me whether this is the right one, and advice me on what cable(s) to get?

Comment: Could [this](http://www.amazon.co.uk/JUSTOP-Internal-Antenna-PCI-Express-Connector/dp/B008KQAQEG/ref=pd_sim_computers_3) be the right connector?